# How do I merge all product tables while adding new column?

Tags: php, mysql, database

### Summary

I have many tables that hold product information. The tables are all named like this:

```
p_productCategory
```

Here is some real data (showing only three for space)

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_global    |
+---------------------+
| orders              |
| p_audio_buzzers     |
| p_audioaccessories  |
| p_batteries_primary |
+---------------------+
```

### The Task At Hand

I need to consolidate all these tables into ONE table. They all have the same column names:

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Datasheets               | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Image                    | varchar(85)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DigiKey_Part_Number      | varchar(46)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Manufacturer_Part_Number | varchar(47)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Manufacturer             | varchar(49)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Description              | varchar(34)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Quantity_Available       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Factory_Stock            | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Unit_Price               | decimal(9,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty                      | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Minimum_Quantity         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Packaging                | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Also, I need to add a new column "category", which would be the table name, ie: **audioaccessories**, **batteries_primary**

**Question:**

How would I go about making a new "products" table, and inserting all the records from all the tables prefaced with a p_  ?

Thank you for looking. I am stuck. I looked at some other "merge table" questions on here, but none were similar enough for me to use.

Comment: Create stored procedure which collects all the data into destination table using dynamic SQL. Or (I think this is more simple, taking into account that this task must be performed once) collect table names (using `SHOW TABLES LIKE`), copypaste into any text editor and convert to SQL script.

Comment: [`INSERT … SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) exists.

Answer (score 0):

Write a query by using `UNION` between all the tables. Make sure to statically add "category" for each projection. Attach the query block right after `CREATE TABLE` segment.

**Example:**
`CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS` 
 `SELECT *,'audio_buzzers' AS category FROM p_audio_buzzers`
 `UNION`
 `SELECT *,'audioaccessories' AS category FROM p_audioaccessories`
 `UNION`
 `SELECT *,'batteries_primary' AS category FROM p_batteries_primary`